# How do you create a form that builds a URL based on multiple selections the user made?

Tags: javascript, forms, url

I would like to create a form that builds a URL based on the users selection of mulitple properties. For example, on my site (GaHomesDigest.com) I have a property search function that searches based on tags, etc, but what I want is a new url.

So the url builder would be:

```
URL + CITY [selected]+ Bedrooms + Etc
```

Any ideas on this, just a link to a working example would be great. The ones I have found are with one selection.

For clarity's sake, here's an example.

The form will have a city field, bedrooms, bathrooms and price range.

If the user selects Atlanta 5 Bedrooms 3 bathrooms 0 to 200, I want the user to be taken to domain/atlanta/bedrooms/5/bath/3/max-price/200/

I was thinking a simple javascript, onclick [selector0] + [selector1] etc would work, but I'm not sure if that's right.

If I knew the right "words" to search for I would be able go and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: So, you're basically asking how to serialize form's input names+values to a fullworthy query string?

Comment: You just went over my head, but basically the urls are already there sitting there, but there's so many of them, this would search it. The url might look like domain.com/city/beds/5/basement/yes

Comment: You may want to edit and clarify the question more to elaborate the functional requirement in proper technical detail. I have now no idea anymore what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to edit it.  Half the battle is knowing how to describe what you are searching for.

Comment: Providing use case examples is already more than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand what you mean... Will something like this work:

```
var urlTemplate = '/{city}/beds/{beds}/basement/{bsmnt}';
var city = $('#city').val();
var beds = $('#beds').val();
var bsmnt = $('#bsmnt').val();


$('#myForm').attr('action', urlTemplate.replace(
    '{city}', city).
    '{beds}', beds).
    '{bsmnt}', bsmnt);
```

Now you have your action filled with values of the inputs. Put this code inside a function called when you need this url formed. I am using jQuery.

Comment: This is fundamentally what I was looking for, but wasn't sure how to get this to work.

Comment: I have to test it out first.  I'll "check" you though when I do.